# Avoid instantiating objects in loops - SONAR complaince

Tags: java, generics

**Instantiating objects inside loop is the common approach every developer do's.**

We instantiate different objects with different generic and collection types inside loops which is not suggestable. Defining a private method to get instance can solve the issue. But I m looking for the generic approach to attain the same.

Example: In the below code

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(xList)) {
        for (final X x : xList) {
        final List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<Y>();
        final Z z = new Z();
        populateYList(yList);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(yList)) {
           // do something
        }
    }
```

When we go for generic way, is it object safe? Few of my efforts are below

```
private <T> List<T> getCollectionIntializer(Class<T> type) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }


private <T> T getIntializer(Class<T> clazz) {
        T c = null;
        try {
            c = (T) clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Finally my code looks like

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(xList)) {
        for (final X x : xList) {
        final List<Y> yList = getCollectionIntializer(Y.class);
        final Z z = getIntializer(Z.class);
        populateYList(yList);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(yList)) {
           // do something
        }
    }
```

Is it a secure way to segregate these methods in separate static class so that it can be used in all the classes. Instantiating objects from out of scope of the class?

Share the thought and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all depends on what are you doing with collection or object you get with these methods. If someone may call it with types you're not expected and this can lead to error, I think it would be better to limit access to these methods or class somehow.

If you're expecting only subclasses with a specific superclass in these methods, you may use wildcards. For example:

```
private <T extends Number> List<T> getCollectionIntializer(Class<T> type) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
```

And if I call getCollectionIntializer method in this way:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
List<SomeClass> list = someClass.getCollectionIntializer(someClass.getClass());
```

I'll will get a compilation error:

```
Error:(27, 41) java: method getCollectionIntializer in class SomeClass cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<T>
  found: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends SomeClass>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: capture#1 of ? extends SomeClass
    upper bound(s): java.lang.Number
```

May be it will be helpful.

Comment: Ya. I do agree with your statement "It would be better to limit access to these methods or class somehow". But I need to overcome these and still looking for any feasible solutions

Answer (score 1):

Reflection should be avoided if at all possible. There nothing here that appears to require it.

Generally for collections a type parameter is sufficient, so we don't have to do anything too difficult.

```
    final List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<>();
```

To create an object, the Abstract Factory pattern is typically applied. `java.util.function.Supplier` provides a common interface. A `Supplier` can be obtained using the method reference to a constructor syntax.

```
    myCode(MyZ::new);
```

[...]

```
    public static <Z> List<Z> myCode(Supplier<Z> supplier) {
        List<Z> zList = new ArrayList<>();
        zList.add(suppler.get());
        return zList;
    }
```